# Rethink db Web interface not accessable

Tags: docker-compose, rethinkdb

I want to see the web interface of my rethink db which I run as a docker container. I read here how to invoke the web interface https://rethinkdb.com/docs/administration-tools/. But it does not work in my case. When I type **localhost:28015** nothing is shown. Here is the docker compose file in which the rethinkdb container is defined.

```
services:
   rethinkdb:
   image: rethinkdb:2.3.5
   ports: "28015:28015"
```

Can you tell me why it is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should expose port `8080` in your file instead of `28015`.

Comment: that is correct, thanks! but it is also mandatory to have the -- bind all command.